# Округление чисел

Tags: php

Например, у нас есть формула `6*5/2`. Если посчитать, то у нас получится -15. А если мы сделаем такую формулу `7*5/2`, то у нас получиться - 17.5! Вопрос: как сделать так, чтоб  целое число осталось без изменения, а к дробным числам добавить 0.5?

Comment: Как сделать округление? А то фраза: 
Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтоб целое число осталось без изменения, а к дробным числам добавить 0.5
Просто убивает!

Comment: Стоп стоп что за? 65/2 = 15 (32.5)? 75/2= 17.5 (37.5)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

```
<?php
$k=17,5;
$k2 = round($k)
echo $k2
?>
```

Comment: @oOKomarOo поставьте галку)

Answer (score 3):

Округление вверх - ceil($num), вниз - floor($num), в ближайшую сторону - round($num). Доки [читаем](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.math.php).